# get a value from a handler class

Tags: java, corba

I wrote a `CORBA` based program. I use this code to call two functions:

```
AMI_StockQuotesServerHandler cbHandler = new AMICallbackHandler()._this(orb);
  ((_StockQuotesServerStub)server).sendc_getQuoteByName(cbHandler, "GOOGLE");
 ((_StockQuotesServerStub)server).sendc_getQuoteByISIN(cbHandler, "GOL");
try
            {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep ( 100 );
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
// How to get the received value here ?
```

And I receive the result in the class `AMICallbackHandler`:

```
public class AMICallbackHandler extends AMI_StockQuotesServerHandlerPOA
{
    @Override
    public void getQuoteByName(stock_quote ami_return_val) {
        System.out.println(ami_return_val.name + ": " + ami_return_val.price);
    }

    @Override
    public void getQuoteByName_excep(ExceptionHolder excep_holder) {
        System.out.println("Not found ");

    }

    @Override
    public void getQuoteByISIN(stock_quote ami_return_val) {
        System.out.println(ami_return_val.isin + ": " + ami_return_val.price);
    }

    @Override
    public void getQuoteByISIN_excep(ExceptionHolder excep_holder) {
        System.out.println("Not found ");
```

I tried to add something like this but I get the message

> method did not override method from its superclass

```
private static int priceByName;
private static int priceByIsin;
....
....
priceByName=ami_return_val.price;
...
...
priceByIsin=ami_return_val.price;
...

@Override
public int checkPrice(){
    if(priceByIsin==priceByName)
        return priceByIsin;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you see this error message because the class inherited by the one class where `checkPrice()` method resides doesn't have `checkPrice()` method. In order to resolve this issue you probably should remove `@Overrides` annotation.